# Issue with drupal 7 migrate (and migrate extras) module. Address fields not migrating

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have an issue with a Drupal 7 data migration whereby I am using the migrate module with migrate extras and an address field.  My entire migration is working fine except for the address field data.

There seem to be plenty OLD examples around, but none that use the subfield notation that migrate supports.  I am must be missing something really obvious.
Many thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
class DOCInfoMigration extends JoomlaMigration {
 public function __construct() {

   parent::__construct();

   $this->description = t('Loads early profiles data to DOCInfo profile');

    /********* Source *********/
    // MySQL database as source
   $query = Database::getConnection('default', 'default')
            ->select('DOCInfo', 'u')
            ->fields('u', array('uid',
                                'first',
                                'last',
                                'phone',
                                'phonetype',
                                'dob',
                                'gender',
                                'membertype',
                                'year',
                                'make',
                                'model',
                                'new_used',
                                'tshirt_it',
                                'street',
                                'apt',
                                'city',
                                'state',
                                'zipcode'));

   $this->source = new MigrateSourceSQL($query);

    $this->destination = new MigrateDestinationProfile2('doc_info'); // use machine name of profile

    /*********** Map **********/
    // Create a "map" which is used to translate primary keys*/
   $this->map = new MigrateSQLMap($this->machineName,
     array(
       'uid' => array(
         'type' => 'int',
         'alias'=> 'u'
       ),
       ),
     MigrateDestinationProfile2::getKeySchema()      
   );

   /*********** Connect DOCInfo to user **********/
   $this->addFieldMapping('uid', 'uid');

   /******* Field mappings ******/
   $this->addFieldMapping('language')->defaultValue('en');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_fname','first');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_fname:language')->defaultValue('en');

   $this->addFieldMapping('field_lname','last');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_lname:language')->defaultValue('en');

   $this->addFieldMapping('field_home_phone','phone');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_home_phone:language')->defaultValue('en');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_phone_type','phonetype');

   $this->addFieldMapping('field_dob','dob');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_doc_gender','gender');

   $this->addFieldMapping('field_doctype','membertype');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_docbikeyear','year');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_docmake','make');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_docmodel','model');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_docmodel:language')->defaultValue('en');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_docnewused','new_used');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_italian_t_shirt','tshirt_it');

   $this->addFieldMapping('field_address:thoroughfare','street');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_address:premise','apt');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_address:locality','city');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_address:administrative_area','state');
   $this->addFieldMapping('field_address:postal_code','zipcode');


   /*** Unmapped destination fields ***/
   $this->addUnmigratedDestinations(array('revision_uid',
                                          'field_address',
                                          'field_address:sub_administrative_area',
                                          'field_address:dependent_locality',
                                          'field_address:sub_premise',
                                          'field_address:organisation_name',
                                          'field_address:name_line',
                                          'field_address:first_name',
                                          'field_address:last_name',
                                          'field_address:data',
                                          'field_dob:timezone',
                                          'field_dob:rrule',
                                          'field_dob:to',));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

AddressField expects a country in order to know what subfields to use.

Try adding this BEFORE your other address field mappings:

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_address', 'country')
     ->defaultValue('US');
```

(followed by

```
$this->addFieldMapping('field_address:thoroughfare','street');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_address:premise','apt');
$this->addFieldMapping('field_address:locality','city');
```

etc.)